# How do I make the black icons (x) and bars disappear for larger screens/ what code should I write for the css

Tags: css

So what I am trying to do is make my menu icons only on smaller screens like a phone or tablet and text appear on larger screens like laptop or desktop. I’ve tried changing up the media query and CSS but no avail. Exactly, what should I type in my code to fix this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpiir.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFpVL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDy9N.jpg)

Comment: Hi Jose, can you read this before you post. It will help you write questions that others will be willing and able to answer. Posting screenshots of your code isn't helpful as no one can reproduce your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be easier if you just googled hamburger menu and selected one of the schemes, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have missed is that the media query is targeting a max-width of 768px and is only applying your styles to that condition. But the element is still being rendered because you have not set a condition for it to not display.

```css
/* Hide menu button by default */
.menu {
  display: none;
}

/* Show menu button when condidion is met */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="menu">Menu</button>
```

I would personally write mobile first and in this instance just add display: none to a min-width media query but your code base appears to be using max-width so best to stick with that and just add display: none outside of the existing media query